# No space left on device in Sagemaker model training

Tags: amazon-web-services, keras, amazon-sagemaker

I'm using custom algorithm running shipped with Docker image on p2 instance with AWS Sagemaker (a bit similar to https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/scikit_bring_your_own.ipynb)

At the end of training process, I try to write down my model to output directory, that is mounted via Sagemaker (like in tutorial), like this:

```
model_path = "/opt/ml/model"
model.save(os.path.join(model_path, 'model.h5'))
```

Unluckily, apparently the model gets too big with time and I get the
following error:

> RuntimeError: Problems closing file (file write failed: time = Thu Jul
>   26 00:24:48 2018
>
> 00:24:49 , filename = 'model.h5', file descriptor = 22, errno = 28,
>   error message = 'No space left on device', buf = 0x1a41d7d0, total
>   write[...]

So all my hours of GPU time are wasted. How can I prevent this from happening again? Does anyone know what is the size limit for model that I store on Sagemaker/mounted directories?

Comment: Could you provide some more info about the exact object type that `model` is? If it's an MXNet model, it might make sense to use the [save method](http://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/test/api/python/model.html#save-the-model) to directly save it to an S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you train a model with `Estimators`, it [defaults to 30 GB of storage](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/estimators.html), which may not be enough. You can use the `train_volume_size` param on the constructor to increase this value. Try with a large-ish number (like 100GB) and see how big your model is. In subsequent jobs, you can tune down the value to something closer to what you actually need.

Storage costs [$0.14 per GB-month of provisioned storage](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/). Partial usage is prorated, so giving yourself some extra room is a cheap insurance policy against running out of storage.

Comment: Is there a way to increase the training_volume_size if you are just running a training job from the CDK and not using `Estimators`?

Comment: I see training_volume_size is actually just the additional volume size I can specific in the resource config but that isn't the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the SageMaker Jupyter notebook, you can check free space on the filesystem(s) by running `!df -h`. For a specific path, try something like `!df -h /opt`.